# Path sum in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

Given a directed acyclic graph, determine if any branch returns a path sum that equals 22. In the example below, such a path can be found at (7 + 8 + 3 + 4). What is the run time complexity of such an algorithm?

```
      7  
     / \  
    8   6  
   / \ / \  
  2   3   8  
 /   /    \     
5   4      1
```

This is what I came up with.

```
public boolean hasPathToSum(Node root, int sum)
{
    if (root == null) return false;
    if (root.value == sum && (root.left == null && root.right == null))
        return true;

    return hasPathToSum(root.left, sum - root.value) || hasPathToSum(root.right, sum - root.value);
}
```

Any better suggestions on improving the complexity?

Comment: The data structure looks more like a binary tree than a graph (a node has `left` & `right` instead of a list of edges). In this case, the complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of nodes in the tree, since you're visiting each node ones.

Comment: If it's a tree a breadth-first traversal can be done in `O(n)`. A forest could be traversed in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Not really, even in this simple example, the node "3" is visited twice.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that `3` has two parents. You are right, it's a DAG, not a binary tree.

Comment: The worst case would be a graph where every node on depth `i` connects to every node on depth `i+1`. I think this requires a `O(n^2)` breadth-first traversal.

Comment: If the DAG is actually a rooted tree, as your diagram shows, your algorithm is fine. But if it's a rooted DAG, then your algorithm will evaluate all possible paths, requiring time exponential in the number of edges. You should look at approaches that do a proper depth- or breadth-first search (with a "visited" map or flags in nodes) of the DAG. Your algorithm also misses the point that a DAG doesn't necessarily have one root or even just one connected component, so it's wrong in a number of ways.

Comment: Op should clarify on the variety of possible inputs. Prior to this any attempt to solve this would be speculative.

Comment: @Gene - I would say the picture above is definitely a rooted DAG (root being 7) since child nodes contain more than 1 parent. Based on that, why is it exponential and how can I optimize it? Maybe I am not understanding, but pseudo-code might help.

Comment: It's a rooted _tree_, which is a subset of rooted DAGs.  In a general dag, any node can have more than one child and more than parent. The only restriction is no cycles. There can also be >1 connected component. E.g. a diamond graph will have exponential behavior with your algorithmn: `<><><>`. I told you how to optimize. Start with a _graph_ DFS or BFS algorithm that visits every vertex and edge exactly once.

Answer (score 2):

If all values in the graph are nonnegative you can solve this problem in O((n + m) * sum) using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). In your case sum is fixed and equal to 22, so the solution is effectively linear.

Memoization is a technique not to compute the same value twice. Note that `hasPathToSum(root, sum)` is a pure function: its result depends only on arguments, it has no side effects. It means that we can save the result of this function into some map `(root, sum) -> bool` (probably a HashMap or a TreeMap in Java, I cannot say precisely as I'm not familiar with the language).

Now, when calling the function, we check if its arguments are presented in the map. If yes, just return saved value. Otherwise calculate it, save into the map and return. This way the function will be really computed only once for any set of arguments.

The last optimization works only with nonnegative values. Note that the result of `hasPathToSum(v, x)` is false if x < 0. So you can make a cutoff: just return false immediately if this is the case. This optimization ensures that, for each node, `hasPathToSum` will be called with at most 23 different sum values, yielding the aforementioned running time.